# Laravel5.6 + vuejs bootstrap 3.3.7 dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, popperjs

I use laravel 5.6, vuejs, and Bootstrap 3.3.7 as soon as I add the file app.js my dropdown stops working it asks popper.js
When I added popper it returns another error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of null at new Popper "
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4K4F.png)

Comment: Click index.js:142 in console where error is displayed as per seen from your attachment. And send screen shot of it @fouzo

Answer (score 0):

I think the popper plugin you installed needs jquery. Can you try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-popperjs